# How does c++ handle memory for local variables when passing them by reference?

Tags: c++, memory, compilation

I think I get the functionality -- passing a reference into a function passes the address, so modifications to `a_val` and `b_val` in `get_point` below change the values of variables in `calling_func`.

What I don't understand is how this is actually achieved -- are the values moved to heap space and their addresses passed into `get_point`? Or can addresses from the `calling_func` stack frame be passed into `get_point` and modified there?

```
void calling_func() {
    float a, b;
    get_point(a,b);
}
void get_point(float& a_val, float& b_val) {
    a_val = 5.5;
    b_val = 6.6;
}
```

Comment: Objects on the stack have addresses, too. The stack is just an area of RAM; the heap is just another area.

Comment: Most likely the implementation passed pointers to the original variables and then modifies them by dereferencing the pointers. But how the compiler does it "under the hood" is largely irrelevant to you as the programmer. As long as you follow the language rules you'll get the expected result. How it's achieved could vary from compiler to compiler and is generally not something you need to be concerned about.

Comment: The compiler may very well inline this function anyway and just operate on the values in calling_func. They may not even exist on the stack in calling_func, possibly existing only in register space. Look at your compiled code at different optimization levels to see what's going on.

Comment: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) is often useful when you want to see what code different compilers generate with different options. Check it out. Compare your code with gcc defaults versus GCC with `-O2` or `-O3` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Or can addresses from the calling_func stack frame be passed into get_point and modified there?`

- Exactly; the stack grows downwards for each function when called, and the callers stack space above is still valid when calling the callee. Usually this is achieved by passing a pointer wherever the argument would've been passed, using a `lea` instruction:

```
lea rcx, [rsp + offset to a]
lea rdx, [rsp + offset to b]
call get_point
```

Inside of `get_point`, rcx and rdx (assuming a win64 calling convention), are dereferenced and moved into xmm registers in order to operate on these variables as floating-point numbers. This is achieved for example using `movss`:

```
movss xmm0, [rcx]  // this is where the actual dereferencing of the references in question happens
movss xmm1, [rdx]
```

Furthermore, I suggest checking out Compiler Explorer ( https://godbolt.org/ ), if you want to see the actual assembly generated by your compiler.